# In shiny, using dashboard plus, how to control widget style?

Tags: r, shinydashboard

Currently I am using Shiny dashboardplus, anyone know how to control this wedget 
in terms of opacity , height and width

```
widgetUserBox(title = "Glara Johanthen",
                shiny::actionButton(inputId='Name', label="Click here"),
                type = 2, src = "https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg", color = "green")
```

Comment: height and width are options, see documentation. For opacity you probably need some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To control the opacity and other css, add the following to your dashboardBody

```
  tags$style(".widget-user-header.bg-green { opacity: 0.5 !important; }"),
```

Or other parts of the widget, if you want to control the opacity outside of the header, in this example above